# Remove part of string in table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table where one field named "version" contains the string "MyProgram nnnnnn".
I now wish to replace these strings so that they are only "nnnnnn", thereby remove the prepending "MyProgram ".

Is this possible, and if so, how would I do this?

Comment: can you provide some more sample data and possibilities that can be as string in that column ?

Comment: look in [mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/string-functions.html) the replace- function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the pattern is `"MyProgram nnnnnn"` maning string like `VB 1.3, Mysql 5.6, PHP 5.4` etc then you can do the following

```
update tablename 
set col = substring_index(col,' ',-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Replace function,

```
SELECT VERSION,  
REPLACE(VERSION,'MyProgram nnnnnn','nnnnnn')   
FROM FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Replace() function for MySQL

```
update table set columnname = REPLACE(columnname, 'MyProgram ', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

```
SELECT REPLACE(VERSION, 'MyProgram ', '')
FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

You want:

> I now wish to replace these strings so that they are only "nnnnnn"

Shortest solution:

`SELECT 'nnnnnn'`

---

**Specify your pattern of the content of this column!**

Answer (score 0):

SELECT VERSION,
REPLACE(VERSION,'MyProgram nnnnnn','nnnnnn')
FROM FROM tablename

Regards,
Praveen Nelge