# Replace part of string in table column

Tags: sql, string, replace, oracle10g

Using [Remove part of string in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23907373/remove-part-of-string-in-table) as an example, I want to change part of my string in my database column with a different string.

Ex:

Database says `E:\websites\nas\globe.png` , `E:\websites\nas\apple.png` and etc

I want it to say `\\nas\globe.png`, `\\nas\apple.png`,

Only part I want to replace is the `E:\websites\` not the rest of the string

How do I do this?

So far I have:

```
SELECT file_name,  
REPLACE(file_name,'E:\websites\','\\nas\')   
FROM t_class;
```

I just referenced http://nntp-archive.sybase.com/nntp-archive/action/article/%3C348_1744DC78C1045E920059DE7F85256A8B.0037D71C85256A8B@webforums%3E

and used:

```
SELECT REPLACE('E:\websites\web\Class\Main_Image\','E:\websites\web\Class\Main_Image\','\\nas\class_s\Main_Image\') "Changes" 
FROM DUAL;
```

but once again it wouldn't change O.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a reference at [how to replace string values of column values by SQL Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28297168/how-to-replace-string-values-of-column-values-by-sql-stored-procedure)

by doing the following:

```
UPDATE t_class SET file_name = 

REPLACE

(file_name, 'E:\websites\web\Class\Main_Image\No_Image_Available.png', '\\nas\class_s\Main_Image\No_Image_Available.png');
```

so only difference is the `update` and `=` sign

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you may need to double up on the back slashes:

```
SELECT file_name,  
       REPLACE(file_name,'E:\\websites\\', '\\\\nas\\')   
FROM t_class;
```

Comment: When I run this in InfoMaker, there is no errors similarly to my format. However, when I test this and select * from my table the E:\website ones still show up

Answer (score 1):

For the fun of it, using `regexp_replace`:

```
SQL> with tbl(filename) as (
  2  select 'E:\websites\nas\globe.png' from dual
  3  union
  4  select 'E:\websites\nas\apple.png' from dual
  5  )
  6  select filename, regexp_replace(filename, 'E:\\websites', '\\') edited
  7  from tbl;

FILENAME                  EDITED
------------------------- --------------------
E:\websites\nas\apple.png \\nas\apple.png
E:\websites\nas\globe.png \\nas\globe.png

SQL>
```

Comment: It looks like yours isn't based on a long listing but rather a specific listing the user looks for... my example there are like 50 fields for file_name column ... all that have a different `"".png` file name at the end of the string aka I need it too look at all fields and replace the `E:\websites...etc`
I tried doing: `with t_class(file_name) as (
  select 'E:\websites\web\Class\Main_Image' from dual
  )
  select file_name, regexp_replace(file_name, 'E:\websites\web\Class\Main_Image', '\\nas\class_s\Main_Image\') edited
  from t_class;` and still it wasn't replace ? makes no sense why

Comment: As Gordon said you need to escape the slashes: `with t_class(file_name) as 
( select 'E:\websites\web\Class\Main_Image' from dual 
) 
select file_name, regexp_replace(file_name, 'E:\\websites\\web\\Class\\Main_Image', '\\\nas\class_s\Main_Image\') edited from t_class;`

Comment: Even with the extra  \\
it doesn't work; however, I submitted my answer above. I found out I needed the `update` part for my coding example